# Integralização Delphi + Scanner

Tags: delphi, scanner

Alguém conhece algum componente ou modo de integrar uma aplicação feita em Delphi XE2 + Scanner, preciso salvar o que está sendo digitalizado.

Comment: Atualmente a melhor opção é usar um componente para isso presente na suite JEDI VCL. não lembro bem o nome...

Comment: Também gostaria de usar o JEDI, mas preciso saber qual..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guilherme o único componente que conheço de Scanner para o Delphi é o TWAIN.

Ele havia sido descontinuado mas uma outra comunidade fez atualizações para o XE2.

Link do componente:

[Link](http://www.kluug.net/delphitwain.php)

Comment: Conheço este, porém estou tendo problema com uma digitalizadora da Epson, começa a digitalização e logo tenho um erro: "floating point invalid operation". Tem ideia do que pode estar acontecendo?